# Dynamic dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Python v3.4.2

I've created a dictionary from a list of keys and stored the number of times the key occurs.

My code works as intended, but I'm unsure WHY it works:

count_dict = {key: key_list.count(key) for key in key_list}

I see that for every key in key_list, I'm adding 'key' and 'count' value pairs to the dictionary. But why does this syntax work? I would expect to need to declare an empty dictionary and then add the key value pairs within a for..in.. loop.

It appears to work for lists as well. But when I try something such as:

print(x) for x in key_list

I get a syntax error.

Comment: read a basic tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

this is known as a dictionary comprehension

it was introduced in python 2.7

see: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

there are also set comprehensions, list comprehensions, generator statements...

however you are right you cannot just write arbitrary code and expect it to work

ie `print(x) for x in key_list` is indeed a syntax error